# Create Cloud9 instance via commandline

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud9

I am trying to create cloud9 environments for conducting interviews on DevOps, for that I need a way to create a cloud9 instance via command line so that i can such environments on demand for the interview duration and deleted once done without risking my AWS credentials

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from command line using AWS CLI command create-environment-ec2.
Here's the link: [create-environment-ec2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloud9/create-environment-ec2.html)